# Insert multiple items into PostgreSQL table

Tags: python, postgresql

I would like to insert multiple rows in PostgreSQL table. I attached the program. I used a list of items: new_record = ['one','two','three'].
Actually, this list will be filled with 100000 items from Amazon products but now I fill with 3 items. I make a for loop to iterate but it filled with only one element.
I would like to print all the items. For example:

```
"INSERT INTO products(products_amazon) VALUES ('one')"
"INSERT INTO products(products_amazon) VALUES ('two')"
"INSERT INTO products(products_amazon) VALUES ('three')"
```

I will appreciate any help.

```
import psycopg2
from pprint import pprint

database = "amazon_products"
host = "localhost"
user = "postgres"
password = "123QQsuccess"


class DatabaseConnection:
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.connection = psycopg2.connect(database=database, host=host, user=user, password=password)
            self.connection.autocommit = True
            self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        except:
            pprint('Cannot connect to database')

    def insert_new_record(self):
        new_record = ['one','two','three']
        for item in new_record:
            insert_command = "INSERT INTO products(products_amazon) VALUES ('" + item + "')"
        pprint(insert_command)
        self.cursor.execute(insert_command)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    database_connection = DatabaseConnection()
    database_connection.insert_new_record()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for whatever reason you really want to insert all statements at once, just concatenate all insert statements using **;** and sent it as a single string to the database.

Like this:

```
"INSERT INTO products(products_amazon) VALUES ('one');
INSERT INTO products(products_amazon) VALUES ('two');
INSERT INTO products(products_amazon) VALUES ('three');"
```

Comment: I would like to insert about 100000 items from Amazon into a postgresql table and I have to insert items from a list returned by the products links

Comment: Well, I'm not familiar with the products links from Amazon, but regarding inserting 100k items to a table you don't have many options: 1) COPY from a text file 2) the compact INSERT statement suggested by Jestin and 3) a chain of INSERT statements concatenated by semicolon as suggested above. All you have to do is to convert this list of yours (using a loop) into a huge string with INSERT statements and when leaving the loop you execute this string in the database. Sorry for not being able to help you with the python thing..

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried like this.? I hope It'll work  in your case

```
INSERT INTO products(products_amazon) VALUES ('one'), ('two'), ('three')....
```

Comment: How can I use for 100000 items?

Comment: You can run a loop and append it to the prepared query.Since it's simple insert it'll be very fast. But for safer side chunk the items to 10,000 and make multiple queries.

Comment: Actually, as you can see in the code I use a for loop but it added only the last element. How can I use the for loop to insert all the items?

Comment: You can also try `COPY FROM` of postgress

`COPY myTable FROM '/path/to/file/on/server' ( FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER('|') );`

Comment: You are running query for each item, Instead you shoul'd prepare a bulk query and finally run the query